# Module not found: Can't resolve '@vercel/turbopack-ecmascript-runtime/dev/client/hmr-client.ts'

Tags: next.js, server, turbopack

I'm working on a Next.js project and I'm encountering an unusual error. When I click on a button in my application, I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@vercel/turbopack-ecmascript-runtime/dev/client/hmr-client.ts'
```

The error seems to be related to Next.js's internal workings, specifically its hot module replacement (HMR) system. I'm not trying to import anything from `@vercel/turbopack-ecmascript-runtime` directly in my code.

Here are the steps I've taken to try to resolve this issue:

1. Deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled my dependencies with `npm install` (I've also tried with `yarn install`).
2. Updated Next.js to the latest version with `npm update next` (also tried with `yarn upgrade next`).

Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions on how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

I was seeing it too using next dev, have not resolved it. The errors weren't very helpful.

Trying next build see errors for it gave errors about react-dom and the help around that was talking about strict mode seemed mostly a blind-alley.

Prior to getting error I was working additional functionality that used a new function around swr and this started. Tried reverting and it wasn't until I realized I'd moved it out of the page to an app/actions.js.

I think the issue is that switched it to server side not client side rendering. Moving it back to my index.js solved it locally for me.